# How to change CSS of child element using attribute selector

Tags: css, attributes, selector

I want to hide a div when it belongs to a parent div which has the attribute data-ontarget set to true.
I tried the following, but nothing happens.

If I remove the class name after the attribute selector in the example below, the whole parent div becomes hidden. So the attribute selector works, but not in combination with the search for a child class.

Here is what I tried:
HTML:

```
<div class="myClass" data-ontarget="false">
        <img src="myImage1.png"/>
        <div class="myImage">This is my image 1</div>
</div>
<div class="myClass" data-ontarget="true">
        <img src="myImage2.png"/>
        <div class="myImage">This is my image 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[data-ontarget="true"] .myImage{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it works just fine for me?

Comment: It works for me. Did you specify the doctype at the top of your HTML page? It  must be <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

Replace opacity property with `display` to hide the element.

```css
.input_container[data="true"]  .awsome_input_border{
  opacity: .5;
}
.input_container[data="false"]  .awsome_input_border{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_container" data="true">

<span class="awsome_input_border"/>
 hide me!!
</div>
<div class="input_container" data="false">

<span class="awsome_input_border"/>
 hide me!!
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.
When I tried your solution, it didn't work either, although it works when I pushed the "Run Code snippet" button in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the proper CSS, which makes your target `div` as hidden.

Refer to the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/1mbnhnsa/).

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="myClass" data-ontarget="false">
    <img src="myImage1.png" />
    <div class="myImage">This is my image 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="myClass" data-ontarget="true">
    <img src="myImage2.png" />
    <div class="myImage">This is my image 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent > div[data-ontarget="true"] {
  display: none;
}
```